# SQL Server - specify time of day to group by

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM GroupTest GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY,timetag)
```

It groups the data by day as expected.

Is there a way I can specify the time of day to group by? For example, I would like the 5th March to be from `'2015-03-05 06:00:00'` to `'2015-03-06 05:59:00'` and grouped as 2015-03-05 (would like a "day" to be from 6 in the morning to 5:59 the following morning.

How could this be achieved?

Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Edit to add example:
As a basic example, if we take this data:

```
id  timetag                 value
1   2015-01-01 06:00:00.000 5
1   2015-01-01 09:00:00.000 5
1   2015-01-01 12:00:00.000 5
1   2015-01-01 15:00:00.000 5
1   2015-01-01 18:00:00.000 5
1   2015-01-01 21:00:00.000 5
1   2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 5
1   2015-01-02 03:00:00.000 6
1   2015-01-02 06:00:00.000 6
1   2015-01-02 09:00:00.000 6
```

I would like the following query:

```
select sum(value) from GroupTest group by datepart(day,timetag)
```

to return

`2015-01-01 21:00:00.000    41` (the first 8 rows)

`2015-01-02 09:00:00.000    12` (the last 2 rows)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Added a basic example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Since your definition of 1 day is "off" by 6 months, you could `GROUP BY` `TimeTag` - 6 hours:

```
SELECT SUM(Value)
FROM GroupTest
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, TimeTag))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM GroupTest GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(hh, -6, timetag))
```

It's the simplest way I can think of to achieve your goal.

Comment: yes, on second thought you and wewesthemenace are correct. it should by -6. editing now.

Answer (score 0):

For `sql server 2012`

```
   SELECT SUM(value)
    FROM GroupTest
    GROUP BY IIF((CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE())<'05:59:00.000'),
    DATEPART(DAY,(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))),
    DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()))
```